# ERD diagram relationships M:N

Tags: database-design, erd

I am confused with a relationships between `Student`----`Receives`----`Grades`.

I think it is:

```
A student receives many grades
A Grade is received by a Student
```

Meaning that it would be a 1:M relationship

Comment: This would suggest that only one student can receive an "A" grade. That's probably false....

Comment: What is your question? PS You are maybe confusing "relationship" as relation(ship)/association with "relationship" as FK. Explain exactly & clearly what you think the relationships are here, what "---" means & why you claim "Meaning ..."--or we can't tell you where you are wrong. Don't ask us to rewrite your textbook. There are many modeling methods, give a reference to yours--textbook name, edition & section. PS Those 2 statements give constraints not relationships, for 2 directions for relation(ship)/association Receives.

Comment: Modeling a relation(ship)/association on 2 (or more) entities is an easily found faq.  Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that the question is: "how can I model the relationship between Student and Grades?"

The start could be a class model like this:

[image]

i.e. a N:M-relationship between Grade and Student.

This typically will be  resolved into a table or class resp. This has the advantage that you can have attributes on grade_received (e.g. date of receiving):

[image]

NB: class names as well as names of entity types should normally be singular (**Grade** instead of **Grades**)